# Compare texts in different columns in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, text

I have following data. Around 1600 rows.

Sheet 1 OLD

```
column A  column B
id_1        aaaa
id_2        bbbb  (text can be quite long)
```

Sheet 2 NEW

```
column A  column B
id_1a       ccc
id_2a       dddd 
id_3a       bbbb
```

I need to compare data from column B between two Sheets and if matched must return corresponding id_number from Sheet1/column A to Sheet2/ColumnC.
Sheet 2 should look like this:

```
id_3a       bbbb     id_2
```

Thank you for your help.
Darina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this one in `C1` (Sheet 2) and drag it down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(Sheet2!B1,Sheet1!B:B,0)),"Not found")
```

above formula works for Excel 2007 and later.

For Excel 2003 use:

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(Sheet2!B1,Sheet1!B:B,0))),
    "Not Found",
    INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(Sheet2!B1,Sheet1!B:B,0))
 )
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. It works very fine. It definitely saved lots of my time.